# Angular ignore unknown field in HttpClient.get()

Tags: json, angular, http, angular-httpclient

I am trying to use `HttpClient.get<ItemResponse>(url)` with type check. Is there anyway to tell angular to ignore unknown fields from response which is not defined in ItemResponse?

Comment: No. But you can use map() and transform the response to whatever you want.

Comment: JB is right. Also, that kinda defeats the purpose of type check.

Answer (score -1):

you can just like JB said use `map` to help with transformation.

```
this.httpClient.get(url).map(response => {
  const myModel = new myModel();
  myModel.propertyA = response.propertyX;
  etc
  return myModel;
}).subscribe();
```

Answer (score -2):

you can achieve this using the **?** operator in your ItemResponse interface like below:

```
interface ItemResponse {
  personName: string;
  age: number;
  profession?: string;
  dateOfBirth?: Date;
}
```

here the profession and dateOfBirth fields are optional since they are using the **?** after them.

hope this helps

Comment: Not sure that this would work. I think that the conditional operator in TypeScript interface just works with what is being defined within the interface. It lets the compiler know that the marked property might be nullable, hence it would work if you omit certain data from the interface, but not if you pass data which are not defined in interface. If I read the question correctly, it is asking about unknown fields from response which are not defined in the interface. But perhaps I do not understand the conditional operator in TypeScript correctly.